How to draw a multiline vector with Inkscape efficiently?
I'm trying to create a multiline vector similar to the image below using Inkscape. The design involves multiple colorful, flowing lines that converge towards the bottom.
I want to know if there's an efficient way to draw these lines without manually creating each one. Ideally, I'm looking for a method that can save time and maintain consistency.
Could someone guide me through an efficient process or provide any tips or techniques to achieve this in Inkscape?
I tried Generate from path > Interpolate between paths , but it just gave some weird shapes rather than the expected type.


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think this has been created with vector software.  It looks more like a raster image, perhaps created in software such as Photoshop/GIMP or similar, perhaps even a 3D render. Who knows.

@BillyKerr How did you came to that conclusion?

@ghost2blade because it doesn't look vector.  Vector art has a very distinctive look, and this just doesn't seem to match that look. There are blurs and gradients that look like a digital painting, possibly made using brushes in a raster painting application. However there is no way to tell precisely how it was done.
